# chi2inv in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

What is the corresponding function for calculating the inverse chi squared distribution in python? In MATLAB, for example, a 95% confidence interval with n degrees of freedom is given by

```
chi2inv(0.95, n)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import chi2
chi2.ppf(0.975, df=2)
```

7.377758908227871

```
octave:4> chi2inv(0.975,2)
ans =  7.3778
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized that the ppf of the scipy distributions corresponds to the inverses while the pdf corresponds to the normal functions.

Comment: Not *pdf*, but *cdf* @LukePolson. See my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Additional information to the current answer:

`chi2.ppf` and `chi2.cdf` are inverse of each-other:

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import chi2
chi2.ppf(0.95, df=5)     # 11.07
chi2.cdf(11.07, df=5)    # 0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

This command from the Statistics Toolbox in Matlab:

```
upperv=chi2inv(1-alpha/2,nu);
```

is identical to this one from the scipy library:

```
from scipy import stats
upperv=stats.chi2.isf(1-alpha/2,nu)
```